# In the electric field we have dielectrics.What about the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, dielectric

Do we have insulators in the magnetic field just like we have dielectrics in the electric field? How are they called and how do they work?

Comment: Are you sure you mean dielectric? Dielectrics block the electric _current_, not the _field_. Superconductors are impermeable to magnetic fields just as conductors are impermeable to electric fields. There's also no such thing as a magnetic current because magnetic monopoles don't exist - unless you count spintronics, where electrons are still the "charge carrier" (magnetic dipole rather than electric monopole), in which case a dielectric would still be an insulator.

Answer (score 1):

There are no insulators against magnetic fields. Unlike electric field lines which can be broken so that negative charges are blocked from reaching the positive terminal, magnetic field lines MUST ALWAYS terminate in the opposite pole.  There are no magnetic monopoles.  Nature will always find a way to return magnetic field lines to the opposite pole.

However, it's possible to re-route magnetic field lines around a shielded area.  If the shielded area is surrounded by a material with higher magnetic permeability, the flux lines of the magnetic field will follow the more permeable material, and will flow around the material to be shielded.

Here is an example of some commercially available materials which will re-route magnetic field lines: http://www.lessemf.com/mag-shld.html

Here is a brief comparison of electric permissivity and magnetic permeability: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html#c4.  It explains why some materials are more permeable to magnetic fields than others.

Answer (score 0):

There are materials, that are diamagnetic. Those show the property of suppressing external magnetic fields by producing an antiparallel one inside of them.
This happens in every material due to Lenz's law: An appearing external magnetic field will cause a current to flow. The current has to go in such a way, that the resulting magnetic field will not amplify this effect, which would violate energy conservation.

However, most materials do not suppress magnetic fields because they show other behaviour, such as ferromagetic or paramagetic properties, that are of larger magnitude and simply override diamagnetism. Typical diamagnetic materials have filled electron orbits such that the total spin = 0, like nobel gases. The best diamagnetic materials are superconductors, which completely expell magnetic fields from its inside.